# How should I log every dispatch call to a Redux store?

Tags: javascript, logging, reactjs, redux

I want to debug my Redux application by logging every action sent to the dispatcher in my the console.

What is generally regarded as the best approach for doing this?

Comment: https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a simple logging middleware, like the example in the [redux middleware docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html):

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.group(action.type)
  console.info('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  console.groupEnd()
  return result
}
```

Or use the [redux-logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger) module, which basically does the same thing.

[With TypeScript, use this annotation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-middlewares) (where `TStore` is the type-name of the root of your state:

```
import { Middleware } from 'redux';

  // ...

const logger: Middleware<{},TState> = store => next => action => {
  console.group(action.type)
  // etc
```